# While executing python script via shell script not logging to file after 2hrs but works fine while executing via only python

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, logging

- while executing step using python on linux server I am getting proper logs but while executing python script via shell script I am not getting logs after 2-3hrs or later.

Comment: Please include relevant parts of your code as well as explain how exactly you are creating the logs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.